# Simple reverse proxy example with Traefik

Tags: traefik

Does anyone have a dead simple configuration example of an incoming http request on port 80 to be redirect to a specific static ip on port 8080 for traefik?

I can't find it absolutely anywhere! Been on their website for a few hours now.

This is their best example from here https://docs.traefik.io/routing/routers/#configuration-example:

```
## Forwarding all (non-tls) requests on port 3306 to a database service
## Static configuration
entryPoints:
  web:
    address: ":80"
  mysql:
    address: ":3306"
```

I would like something like the following from NGINX:

```
events { }

http {
    upstream mop {
        server mop:3000;
    }
    server {
        listen   80;
        server_name  localhost;
        location /mop {
            proxy_pass http://mop;
        }
        location /mop/1 {
            proxy_pass http://mop;
        }
        location /mop/2 {
            proxy_pass http://mop;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

For this simple example, in your static configuration you need to create an `entryPoint` and a `provider`.

The `entryPoint` defines on which port traefik will accept incoming requests and 
the `provider` defines some existing infrastructure component that traefik can query for service discovery. This can be some orchestration system like `Docker` or `Kubernetes`. But in this simple example we need a `File` provider.

```
# Static configuration
[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.web]
    address = ":80"

[providers]
  [providers.file]
    filename = "/path/to/dynamic/conf.toml"
```

In the file provider we define the path to the dynamic configuration. In the dynamic configuration we create a `service` (or backend). This is the server to which we want traefik to route request.

We also need to create a `router`. The router matches rules such as domain or path and routes those requests to the desired `service`. In this example we route the path prefix `/` (all requests) to the service `my-service`, which then points to `http://localhost:8080`.

```
# Dynamic configuration
[http]
  [http.routers]
    [http.routers.my-router]
      rule = "PathPrefix(`/`)"
      service = "my-service"

    [http.services]
      [http.services.my-service.loadBalancer]
        [[http.services.my-service.loadBalancer.servers]]
          url = "http://localhost:8080"
```

Answer (score 2):

from some reference of their site: [doc.traefik.io](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/user-guides/docker-compose/acme-tls/)

I have a `docker-compose.yml` file here base on that.

```yaml
version: "3.3"

services:

  traefik:
    image: "traefik:latest"
    container_name: "traefik"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
      - "8080:8080"
    labels:
      # Enable Traefik for this service, to make it available in the public network
      - traefik.enable=true
      # https-redirect middleware to redirect HTTP to HTTPS
      # It can be re-used by other stacks in other Docker Compose files
      - traefik.http.middlewares.https-redirect.redirectscheme.scheme=https
      - traefik.http.middlewares.https-redirect.redirectscheme.permanent=true
      # Dashboard HTTP here
      - traefik.http.routers.traefik.rule=Host(`traefik.your.domain`)
      - traefik.http.routers.traefik.entrypoints=http
      - traefik.http.routers.traefik.middlewares=https-redirect
      # Dashboard HTTPS here
      - traefik.http.routers.traefik-https.rule=Host(`traefik.your.domain`)
      - traefik.http.routers.traefik-https.entrypoints=https
      - traefik.http.routers.traefik-https.tls=true
      # Use the special Traefik service api@internal with the web UI/Dashboard
      - traefik.http.routers.traefik-https.service=api@internal
      # Use the Let's Encrypt resolver created below
      - traefik.http.routers.traefik-https.tls.certresolver=myresolver
    command:
      # Enable the Traefik log, for configurations and errors
      - --log
      # Enable the Dashboard and API
      - --api
      - "--providers.docker=true"
      - "--providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false"
      # Create an entrypoint "http" listening on address 80
      - --entrypoints.http.address=:80
      # Create an entrypoint "https" listening on address 443
      - --entrypoints.https.address=:443
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.tlschallenge=true"
      # - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.httpchallenge.entrypoint=http"
      #- "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.caserver=https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.email=your@email.addr"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.storage=/letsencrypt/acme.json"
    volumes:
      - "./letsencrypt:/letsencrypt"
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"

  yourServices:
    image: yourServices
    container_name: yourServices
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - traefik.http.routers.yourServices-http.rule=Host(`your.domain`)
      - traefik.http.routers.yourServices-http.entrypoints=http
      - traefik.http.routers.yourServices-http.middlewares=https-redirect
      - "traefik.http.routers.yourServices.rule=Host(`your.domain`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.yourServices.entrypoints=https"
      - "traefik.http.routers.yourServices.tls.certresolver=myresolver"
```

I know it's ugly.  I'm not an expert here.  Fortunately, it works for me. Hope that could do some help.

Comment: See also, https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/middlewares/redirectscheme/ which documents the redirection middleware used here.